# How to Return Custom Policy in Access Token Without "extension_" Prefix Using Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm currently implementing a custom policy in Azure AD B2C and facing an issue where the custom attributes in the access token are prefixed with "extension_". I aim to include custom claims in the access token without this prefix. While I have explored the Azure B2C starter pack, I'm encountering difficulties in manipulating the XML files to achieve this outcome. Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or direct me to comprehensive resources on how to:

Modify the standard or custom policies in Azure B2C to include custom claims in the access token without the "extension_" prefix.
Specifically, which XML files in the B2C starter pack need adjustments, and what specific changes are required to remove the prefix from custom attributes in the token.
Any examples or links to detailed documentation on this process would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

I tried adding my custom policy to OutPut Claims in Relying Party of SignUpOrSignin.xml.

`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_fhirUser" PartnerClaimType="fhirUser" />`

I also added ClaimType in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

```
<ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="extension_fhirUser">
       <DisplayName>fhirUser</DisplayName>
       <DataType>string</DataType>
       <UserHelpText>The fully qualified FHIR resource id associated with the user. (e.g Patient Resource)</UserHelpText>
    </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
```

I am doing changes in Azure B2C Starter Pack for xml files inside LocalAccounts folder.

Comment: PartnerClaimType in the RP is correct. Are you sure you saved and uploaded it, and that it is the policy you are running? It can take up to 15 minutes for the policy to be uploaded and active.

Comment: @rbrayb I have saved and uploaded the xml file containing changes.